# Leap Motion project: WebSocket connection error

Tags: javascript, websocket, leap-motion

I'm working on a school project with leap motion. I have created a simple rock, paper, scissors javascript game where you can use your hand gestures to make your choice. You play against the computer. But unfortunately, I can't test my code because I always get the same error. It's the one below:

`leap-1.1.1.js:381 WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:6437/v6.json' failed:`
`BrowserConnection.setupSocket @ leap-1.1.1.js:381`
`BaseConnection.connect @ leap-1.1.1.js:334`
`Controller.connect @ leap-1.1.1.js:613`
`Controller.loop @ leap-1.1.1.js:670`
`loop @ leap-1.1.1.js:2504`
`(anonymous) @ game.js:8`

I personally have no understanding of what exactly this means and what I need to do to fix this. so I hope you guys can help me. Thanks!

I looked in the file where the error occurs. but this is the file I used to install leap.js. i do not expect to have to change anything in it. I also asked my question to chatGPT but I did not get a useful answer.

I tried this but I'm not sure I looked at it correctly because it honestly doesn't work.
This is the code if you want to take a look at it:

```
// Set up the game
const choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
let playerChoice = null;
let computerChoice = null;
let result = null;

// Listen for the frame event
Leap.loop(frame => {
  // Get the hands in the frame
  const hands = frame.hands;

  // If there are no hands in the frame, return
  if (hands.length === 0) return;

  // Get the first hand in the frame
  const hand = hands[0];

  // Get the fingers in the hand
  const fingers = hand.fingers;

  // Count the extended fingers
  const extendedFingers = fingers.filter(finger => finger.extended);

  // If the hand is in a fist, set the player's choice to null
  if (extendedFingers.length === 0) {
    playerChoice = null;
    return;
  }

  // If one finger is extended, set the player's choice based on the finger
  if (extendedFingers.length === 1) {
    const finger = extendedFingers[0];
    if (finger.type === 0) playerChoice = 'rock';
    if (finger.type === 1) playerChoice = 'scissors';
    if (finger.type === 2) playerChoice = 'paper';
  }
});

// Listen for clicks on the choice buttons
$('#choices button').on('click', function() {
  // Set the player's choice based on the button
  playerChoice = $(this).attr('id');

  // Generate a random computer choice
  computerChoice = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];

  // Determine the result of the game
  if (playerChoice === computerChoice) result = 'tie';
  else if (playerChoice === 'rock' && computerChoice === 'scissors') result = 'win';
  else if (playerChoice === 'paper' && computerChoice === 'rock') result = 'win';
  else if (playerChoice === 'scissors' && computerChoice === 'paper') result = 'win';
  else result = 'lose';

  // Display the result of the game
  $('#result').text(`You chose ${playerChoice}, computer chose ${computerChoice}. You ${result}!`);
});


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Leap Motion Rock Paper Scissors Game</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/leapjs/leap-1.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="game.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="choices">
      <button id="rock">Rock</button>
      <button id="paper">Paper</button>
      <button id="scissors">Scissors</button>
    </div>
    <div id="result"></div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```